# Open URL in browser without toolbar

Tags: java, browser, deployment, applet, toolbar

I'm using the following code to open a specific URL:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
```

That part of the code open the browser and, once open, I build an applet that will load some content.

This is working fine.  But now I got a request to open the browser window without toolbar. That can be achieved using Javascript.  Something like:

```
window.open(''+URL+'','_blank','toolbar=no')
```

Is there any way to pass the argument `'toolbar=no'` when I open the browser using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`?

If not, any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you doing this in a standalone java application, or a java applet running inside the browser?  I think you're doing it from a standalone app since you're accessing the runtime, but you did mention an applet so I want to make sure.

Comment: don't understand how this is related to swing?

Comment: Well, I did not refer swing in the post, but anyway, I'm actually using the above code in a swing application.
Also, I want the applet to run inside the browser and not as a free-floating frame like Andrew said.

Comment: *"I want the applet to run inside the browser and not as a free-floating frame like Andrew said."*   What functionality do the browser decorations bring to the applet?  It sounded more like you wanted to get rid of them.

Comment: The browser dont add anything, but I have other web content that communicates with my applet. That's why I want the applet running in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem I used the following approach...

In my java applet I do a Javascript call using netscape.javascript.JSObject.

In the Javascript I just need to pass the right flags in the window.open

```
window.open(newWindowUrl,'','toolbar=0,resizable=1');
```

This seems to work ok.
Thanks for your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Launch the applet (free-floating, outside the browser) using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The applet will be launched using the applet viewer.

> .. JWS was first offered as a separate download with the release of Java 1.2, and could launch both applications and applets as free floating entities. ..